# C# convert string to uint

Tags: c#, string, uint

So, I have a string of 13 characters.

```
string str = "HELLOWORLDZZZ";
```

and I need to store this as ASCII representation (hex) in a uint variable. How do I do this?

Comment: NOTE: This original string is not hex

Comment: What do you mean is not hex... ascii representation IS a string btw..

Comment: See my edit for the new string

Comment: I do... I am not understanding what you mean by "convert to uint" do you mean the sum of the ascii values of all the characters?

Comment: Do you want to convert an ASCII string to HEX first? This line: I need to store this as ASCII representation (hex) in a uint variable is ponderous

Comment: A uint is only 4-bytes long.  An ASCII representation is 1 byte long.  How exactly do you expect to store 13 characters in a 4-byte field?

Comment: I need to store an ASCII representation of my string in a uint variable.

Comment: R. Bemrose - that is exactly my problem. I guess I need to split into 4 chunks.

Comment: The method I am calling only takes uint :( So to make it easier to understand, let say it take in an array of uint[].

Comment: @whyndna: Do you want the sum of the numbers or a list with each number?

Comment: you can easily convert between em, but you will definitely lose data... can I see the method signature?

Comment: WriteToMem(uint value);

@BrunoLM - not sure, whatever is the proper way to represent ASCII as uint

Comment: If you use `WriteToMem(byte value)`, c# will [implicitly cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) it to a `uint` for you.

Comment: @whydna: I'm not sure of what you want to do. Maybe if you tell us a bit we can provide a more accurate answer...

Comment: I'm with everyone else here. This question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`Encoding.ASCII`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.ascii)`.`[`GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes) to convert your string to a `byte` array with ASCII encoding (each character taking one `byte`).  Then, call [`BitConverter.ToUInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.touint32) to convert that byte array to a `uint`.  However, as *@R. Bemrose* noted in the comments, a `uint` is only 4 `byte`s, so you'll need to do some partitioning of your array first.

Comment: How exactly does a uint represent 4 byte string? How does "ABCD" get represented in a uint?

Comment: @whydna, The [7-bit ASCII table](http://www.neurophys.wisc.edu/comp/docs/ascii/) is used to convert between bit representations and characters. So "ABCD" becomes `01000001 01000010 01000011 01000100` which in decimal is "1094861636", the value that the `uint` would contain.

Comment: Awesome. So I just have 1 more question. So I convert my string into Ascii byte array, then I put it through the BitConvert.ToUint32, which returns the value "1145258561" for the string "ABCD". Converting that to HEX I get "44434241" which is awesome! Except one thing- why is it backwards? (41 = A, 42 = B, etc..). I'm sure it has something to do with big endian little endian

Comment: @whydna Sorry, yeah, `BitConverter.ToUInt32` is little endian, so `1145258561` is the correct decimal value for an input of `"ABCD"`. You can reverse the array before calling `BitConverter.ToUInt32` and you will get the decimal value I gave above, which corresponds to `41424344` in hex.

Comment: Great. Works great. Just for any future reference, it is depenent on the endian-ness of your computer system - so you need to check BitConvert.IsLittleEndian and reverse the array if neccessary.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is the method you want

```
Convert.ToUInt32(yourHexNumber, 16);
```

see the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swz6z5ks%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
uint.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

See my comment, but if you want to just convert an ASCII string to Hex, which is what I suspect:

```
public string HexIt(string yourString)
{
    string hex = "";
    foreach (char c in yourString)
    {
        int tmp = c;
        hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
    }
    return hex;
}
```

Comment: += on a string in a loop is a very bad idea!!! This creates a ton of garbage. Use StringBuilder.

Comment: wasn't meant to be efficient, I think most of us are still wondering what the original intent of the question is.

Answer (score 0):

This will convert your `string` (with a Base 16 representation) to a `uint`.

```
uint val = Convert.ToUInt32(str, 16);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I guess I understand what you want in a comment on bdukes answer.

If you want the `hex` code for each character in the string you can get it using LINQ.

```
var str = "ABCD";
var hex = str.Select(c => ((int)c).ToString("X"))
    .Aggregate(String.Empty, (x, y) => x + y);
```

`hex` will be a string `41424344`